# Indentifying Linearly Dependent Vectors: Why do constants cancel out?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am having trouble understanding why the set of vectors (Johnson & Wichern, 2007)

$$\mathbf x_1=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\2\\1
\end{array}
\right]
\mathbf x_2=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\0\\-1
\end{array}
\right]
\mathbf x_3=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\-2\\1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

when letting
$$c_1\mathbf x_1+c_2\mathbf x_2+c_3\mathbf x_3=0
$$

implies that

$$2c_1 - 2c_3=0$$

**References**

Johnson, R. A., & Wichern, D. W. (2007). *Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis* (6th ed.), p.54 Chapter 2, Example 2.2. Upper Saddle River, NJ: Pearson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sum of vectors is equal to $0$, then specifically, it means that the sum of every $n$-th component is equal to $0$, for any $n$. In this case, they're looking at the *second* component, which gives the equation
$$
c_1\cdot(\text{second component of }\mathbf{x}_1) + c_2\cdot(\text{second component of }\mathbf{x}_2) \\+ c_3\cdot(\text{second component of }\mathbf{x}_3) = 0
$$
which is the same as saying
$$
2c_1 + 0c_2 -2 c_3 = 0
$$

Comment: So if there exists one $k$ in $k_nc_n$ such that $k=0$ then the set of $n$ vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: @noumenal Not necessarily. There is no such easy answer to give that let's you just _see_ whether a set of vectors are linearly dependent or not. Some times you're lucky, and a lot of zeroes in the vectors does help. However, ultimately, you would need to set up a system of equations and really check whether there is more than one solution, and that's the only way that always lets you tell.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate $c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3$. The condition on the second coordinates imply said equation.